# Searching with xslt relations and distances

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

```
        <memberuser  name="John">

            <connection>Tim</connection>

            <connection>Mary</connection>
            <connection>Alen</connection>

        </memberuser>


        <memberuser  name="Alen">

            <connection>Jill</connection>

            <connection>Elen</connection>
            <connection>John</connection>

        </memberuser>
```

Suppose i have an xml like the one above. how can i compute and associate by using the xslt the connection of my connection. So for the member user John for ex. Jill which is a connection for Alen is a connection of a connection for John. I want to compute and to show  for every user it connections of connections. i want to compute something like this:

```
<connection>Tim</connection>   

<connection>Mary</connection>

<connection>Alen</connection>

<connectionofconnection>
    <from>Allen</from>
    <name>Jill</name>
</connectionofconnection>
```

Comment: I am afraid your question is not clear. Please show us the expected result of your example. If, as I suspect, you want to construct some sort of a "tree" of connections for each member, consider also the problem of an infinite loop (John -< Alen -< John -< Alen ... in your example).

Comment: i want to compute something like this:  <memberuser  name="John">
    
    <connection>Tim</connection>
    
    <connection>Mary</connection>
    <connection>Alen</connection>
    <connectionofconnection>
        <from>Allen</from>
        <name>Jill</name>
    </connectionofconnection>
</memberuser>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of generations to two (child and grandchild), you could do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**
***Edited to eliminate self and direct connections from the list of second-generation connections.***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="member" match="memberuser" use="@name" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="connection">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('member', .)/connection[not(.=current()/../@name or .=current()/../connection)]" mode="gen2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="connection" mode="gen2">
    <connection thru="{../@name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </connection>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **test input**:

```
<root>
    <memberuser name="Adam">
        <connection>Betty</connection>
        <connection>Cecil</connection>
        <connection>David</connection>
    </memberuser>
    <memberuser name="Betty">
        <connection>Adam</connection>
        <connection>Cecil</connection>
        <connection>Eve</connection>
    </memberuser>
</root>
```

you will receive the following **output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <memberuser name="Adam">
      <connection>Betty</connection>
      <connection thru="Betty">Eve</connection>
      <connection>Cecil</connection>
      <connection>David</connection>
   </memberuser>
   <memberuser name="Betty">
      <connection>Adam</connection>
      <connection thru="Adam">David</connection>
      <connection>Cecil</connection>
      <connection>Eve</connection>
   </memberuser>
</root>
```

Comment: There are two problems: 1- The name of John should not appear in the friends of John through Alen because it is John himself. 2- In case of a common friend Lana  it should not show the connection thru="" because for both Lana is a direct friend. How can i solve this?

Comment: @shark33 Please update your example input and output.

Comment: how can  i extend the xslt in order to show the other friends of friends at a greater depth and show also the depth as attribute just like thru? its ok if i have to re-run every time to go in more depth.

Comment: how can i extend the xslt in order to show the other friends of friends at a greater depth and show also the depth as attribute just like thru? its ok if i have to re-run every time to go in more depth